# How to find out what the exact Throwable class is?

Tags: php, exception, throwable

I have a `try/catch` block where I catch all `Throwable` exceptions.

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Throwable $ex) {
    ...
}
```

How do I, at runtime, figure out what the exact class of the throw exception is? I want to add multiple `catch` blocks to handle different exceptions differently, but am unable to find out the types of exceptions that are thrown.

Comment: get_class: https://3v4l.org/QpqRM - for a list: https://3v4l.org/f8Boe

Answer (score 1):

Try to dump `get_class($ex)` inside your `catch` block. It will give you the class name of `$ex`.

After the class name is found, you can use `catch` with exact class exception.

Comment: `get_class($ex)` outputs the value `Error`. Is it possible to get subclass of Error here? Or would the subclass be shown here if the actual Error subclass was thrown, but in this case the 'parent' Error object is being thrown (not a subclass of it)?

Comment: do you use `echo` or `var_dump` to output the value?

Comment: `var_dump` outputs `string(5) "Error"`.